# Updating Android Studio breaks Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Updating Android Studio from 2.2.1 to 2.2.2 has completely broken my project, since i am unable to access anything related to Google Maps. My project worked fine before the update, but nothing works now. Making an entirely new project based in Google Maps Activity doesn't work either and gives me the exact same crash report and results.

What i have tried:
- Updating all of my SDK's, specifically Google related ones.
- Generated a new Google API Key
- Creating an entirely new project from scratch
- Changed SupportMapFragment to MapFragment

Error i am getting when i try to run my project and an entirely new maps project on my phone (same error(all other gmaps apps work on my phone, so i don't think that's the issue)):

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
```

My build.gradle(new project from scratch):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.simon.afinal"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Standard Maps Activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

Gmaps XML Layout file:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.simon.afinal.MapsActivity"
tools:layout="@layout/activity_maps" />
```

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

use this for get Google map

```
  if (googleMap == null) {

            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                  .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

in xml map in frame layout like

```
 <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

onMapReady Method Like this

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the library you have to import for maps in gradle file is different.
Change your dependencies accordingly

<strike>compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'</strike>

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
```

Declare your class as:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
```

Or be sure your fragment activity is v4 package.

This should work as are the basic steps to get a map

Comment: FragmentActivity is definently v4, using AppCombatActivity makes no difference, same error.

Comment: and what about dependencies? did you change it?

Comment: yes i changed the dependencies as you asked in the new activity i made solely to test it. The dependencies from my old project that worked perfectly before, the dependencies looked like this: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.8.0'`